# Spotify API - Getting 406 Unacceptable On Token Request When Using HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, spotify

In my requests to Spotify's "get token" endpoint using .NET's HttpRequestMessage, I'm getting a 406 (Unacceptable) response.

Here's my post method (fyi, this is not optimized code -- more of a proof of concept):

```
        public static async Task<string> PostForm(HttpClient httpClient, string url, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> nameValueList)
        {
            using (var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
            {
                httpRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(nameValueList);
                using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest))
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm calling that method with this:

```
        public Token GetSpotifyToken()
        {
            var httpClient= new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic MyApiCredsBase64EncodedYesIveConfirmedTheseWork=");

            var url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";
            var grantType = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials");

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>
                (ApiRequest.PostForm(postClient, url,
                new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() { grantType } )
                .GetAwaiter()
                .GetResult());
        }
```

I know that the issue is related to how `grant_type=client_credentials` is getting added to the request. This method, which uses RestSharp, works fine:

```
        public Token GetSpotifyToken()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic MyApiCredentialsBase64Encoded=");
            request.AddParameter("undefined", "grant_type=client_credentials", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(response.Content);
        }
```

But I've tried adding `grant_type=client_credentials` to the HttpRequestMessage object in a few different ways, without success.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, right after I posted this.

In the above code, the line...

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
```

...was causing the problem. Omitting it allowed the code to work.